# Solve Lotka-Volterra model using SciPy

Tags: python, numpy, ode, differential-equations

I have the following Lotka-Volterra model

dN1/dt = N1(1-N1-0.7N2)

dN2/dt = N2(1-N2-0.3N1)

where the 1 and 2 next to N are subscripts.

I want to solve this using SciPy and visualize the results. I want to make a plot with N2 on the y axis and N1 on the N1. If you set N1 to zero in the first equation, you get N2 = 1/0.7 and if you set N2 to zero in the second equation, you get N1 = 0.3/1. The two lines are suppose to intersect. How do I do this in Python?

I read this [tutorial](http://sam-marsh.staff.shef.ac.uk/mas115/docs/PYTHON-Lecture10.pdf) (slides 6 to 16) online. This is what I have so far.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import integrate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def derivN1(y,t):
    yprime=np.array([1-0.7y[0]])
    return yprime

def derivN2(y,t):
    yprime=np.array([1-0.3y[0]])
    return yprime

start=0
end=1
numsteps=1000
time=np.linspace(start,end,numsteps)
y0=np.array([10])

yN1=integrate.odeint(derivN1,y0,time)
yN2=integrate.odeint(derivN2,y0,time)

plt.plot(time,yN1[:])
plt.plot(time,yN2[:])
```

But the plot isn't correct. UPDATE: I think I used the wrong approach. I'm reading another online [tutorial](http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook/LoktaVolterraTutorial). I'll work through the problem some more. In the meantime, if anyone knows how to solve it let me know.

Comment: Can you describe how the plot is incorrect - what you expected, vs. what you actually saw?

Comment: I want a plot where N2 is on the y-axis and N1 are on the x-axis. The lines N1=0.3 and N2=1/0.7 are supposed to intersect. In the plot my code creates, the lines don't intersect and it's not clear which axis is which.

Comment: The way you're describing it sounds rather strange: these equations are coupled, meaning that at each point in time, you have a tuple `(N1(t), N2(t))`. You could plot that tuple with time as an *implicit* parameter, but then you only have *one curve*, not two. If you want to have two curves, one that plots N1 (the dependant variable) vs time (the independant variable), then you can plot a similar thing for N2 vs time. But then your y-axis will represent the value of N2 or N1. I don't understand your second formulation with two graphs. Can you add an image or source?

Comment: Also, are you sure you're not plotting *two* implicit graphs but just with different starting conditions?

Comment: Check out the Lotka-Volterra example in the scipy cookbook: http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook/LoktaVolterraTutorial?action=show&redirect=LoktaVolterraTutorial

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The comment made by @WarrenWeckesser is a very good one, you should start there. I'll merely try to highlight the differences between the implicit plot and the explicit plot.

First, the setup:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import integrate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

time=np.linspace(0,15,5*1024)

def derivN(N, t):
    """Return the derivative of the vector N, which represents
    the tuple (N1, N2). """

    N1, N2  = N
    return np.array([N1*(1 - N1 - .7*N2), N2*(1 - N2 - .3*N1)])

def coupled(time, init, ax):
    """Visualize the system of coupled equations, by passing a timerange and
    initial conditions for the coupled equations.

    The initical condition is the value that (N1, N2) will assume at the first
    timestep. """

    N = integrate.odeint(derivN, init, time)
    ax[0].plot(N[:,0], N[:,1], label='[{:.1f}, {:.1f}]'.format(*init))  # plots N2 vs N1, with time as an implicit parameter
    l1, = ax[1].plot(time, N[:,0], label='[{:.1f}, {:.1f}]'.format(*init))
    ax[1].plot(time, N[:,1], color=l1.get_color())
```

It is important to realize that your equations are coupled and you should present to `odeint` a function that returns the derivative of your coupled equations. Since you have 2 equations, you need to return an array of length 2, each item representing the derivative in terms of the passed in variable (which in this case is the array `N(t) = [N1(t), N2(t)]`).

Then you can plot it at all, using different initial conditions for N1 and N2:

```
fh, ax = plt.subplots(1,2)
coupled(time, [.3, 1/.7], ax)
coupled(time, [.4, 1/.7], ax)
coupled(time, [1/.7, .3], ax)
coupled(time, [.5, .5], ax)
coupled(time, [.1, .1], ax)
ax[0].legend()
ax[1].legend()
ax[0].set_xlabel('N1')
ax[0].set_ylabel('N2')
ax[1].set_xlabel('time')
ax[1].set_ylabel(r'$N_i$')
ax[0].set_title('implicit')
ax[1].set_title('explicit (i.e. vs independant variable time)')
plt.show()
```

[image: time evolution of coupled equations]

You'll notice that both `N1` and `N2` evolve to some final value, but that both values are different. The curves in the implicit plot do not intersect for the given equations.